# How do I model the express key of a wacom tablet?

Tags: modeling, geometry

I'm trying to recreate my wacom tablet in blender and I'm trying to model one of the express keys so that's flat against the actual tablet surface. It's basically just a button shape:

[image]

**Q:** How do I model this shape?

Comment: Could you share some more about what you already tried and where you are stuck?
Otherwise it's a bit difficult to help you

Comment: someone already helped me but basically I attempted to do what he did with he circle but every time I used s it would make a weird shape. I tried cylinder, square with bevels, and a sphere.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add a *Circle* mesh and select half of the vertices.

[image: 1]

Press <kbd>Y</kbd> to separate the selection, and move it away along whichever axis it faces.

[image: 2]

Select all (<kbd>A</kbd>) and press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill the shape with an n-gon.

[image: 3]

In *Edge Select Mode* (<kbd>2</kbd>), select the two longest edges, press <kbd>W</kbd> and select *Subdivide.*

[image: 4]

Select the new edge and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> (*Bevel Tool*). Scroll <kbd>[image: MW] MW</kbd> up once or type <kbd>2</kbd> to get two segments.

[image: 5]

Select everything and press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude the shape.

[image: 6]

Select the center edge and move it down.

[image: 7]

Delete the faces on the bottom.

Finally, select all the sharp edges and bevel them to your liking.

[image: 8]

I'd recommend shading smooth at this point. ;)

---

[image: yipee]

Comment: If that's incredibly useful, please consider to accept the answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers @jasmine

Comment: how? there’s no option for that

Comment: @jasmine [Here's how.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/449452)

Comment: @jasmine I'm curious, when you say "there's no option for that" - where are you looking exactly? Where are you expecting the option to be? It would be good to know as we can make suggestions for improvements to the UI on the Stack Exchange meta site: https://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think i found it, it’s the check mark no? does it only show up on photo answers cause i can’t do it for comments, i can only upvote them. also, why is there no option to reply to certain people? Does everyone who ever commented get notified if i post a comment to my post trying to answer someone?

Comment: @jasmine Yes, it's the "check mark". Yes, you can only "accept" answers (to your own question). Comments on an answer are just that... comments seeking clarification on points raised in the answer. By accepting an answer you are informing other readers that the solution works... it also "thanks" the user who answered and assigns some "rep" to the answerer and yourself for "accepting". You "reply" to users by using the `@` symbol followed by the username (as used above) - this triggers a notification for the user. Although all comments under an answer notify the answerer.